# how to change the vtable symbol to a global symbol?

Tags: c++, gcc, vtable

I have compiled a so file（libarfoundation_core.so） which has a base class ARSRGpuFilter, and a other so file which need dependency the compiled so file could not compiled because " undefined reference to `vtable for cameralink::ARSRGpuFilter'"
[image]

Then, I find the vtable symbol of the ARSRGpuFilter is a Local Symbol, so how to change the vtable symbol of ARSRGpuFilter to a global symbol?

[image]

Comment: Please show a [mre]. You probably have an undefined virtual method in the class

Answer (score 0):

place "**attribute**((visibility("default")))" after "class" to apply attribute to type declaration. it works for me...